ISO-8601 encoding (non-)recurrences
I’m trying to find good / standardized representations of payment recurrences in context of a Python web app. Examples for the values I want to encode are: one-off, monthly and yearly.
Using IS08601 durations I get P1M for monthly and P1Y for yearly. The only obvious option for one-off is null or empty string. An empty string is tricky because it makes it undistinguishable from no choice.
An example for that problem is this HTML snippet which displays one-off as an option that doesn’t validate because it’s required.
<input type="radio" id="one-off" name="recurrence" value="" required />
<label for="one-off">one-off</label>
<input type="radio" id="monthly" name="recurrence" value="P1M" required />
<label for="monthly">monthly</label>
<input type="radio" id="yearly" name="recurrence" value="P1Y" required />
<label for="yearly">yearly</label>

I also looked at repeat rules (F…) and repeating durations (R…) in the standard by neither none of them provide straight forward values for not-repeating / one-off either.
Is there any other part of this (ISO 8601) or another standard that allows to better encode these kind of values?

Why do you have to use an ISO8601 duration, why not use "once"/"monthly"/"yearly" for the values?

They are also used through several sub-systems and in two APIs. It makes sense to me to not invent a new value whenever a new integration comes up that supports one. Encoding recurring dates sounds like something that might have come up in IT history once or twice already ;-)

True but you have an option that cannot be represented using durations so you need a value that you understand to mean once only. Using "once"/"monthly"/"yearly" adds a layer of abstraction that clearly means exactly what you want. Your backend can translate these to whatever you're using to schedule the payments, if that means the ISO8601 durations for recurring payments or the current date and time for a one-off payment, that's up to you.

I was looking for a more elegant solution than having two mappings (translated labels → intermediate values → actual internal representation). Having standardized values would allow me to skip one of those.

Why can't you go directly from value="monthly" to "actual internal representation"? Now you've said this it sounds like "P1M" would be the intermediate value

P1M would be the actual representation (that is then alse exposed to the APIs). That’s exactly the short-cut.

Use once/P1M/P1Y then.
